# How to permanently set matplotlib pyplot style?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I like the ggplot style that is available in matplotlib. So when I'm in an interactive session I typically do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
```

This produces very nice styles. Is there an easy way to make this setting persistent so I don't need to type the above command every time I start up Python?

Comment: Edit matplotlibrc file: https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html

Comment: I can't see a setting for 'style' there. If you do this I think you need to specify all the individual settings manually.

Comment: There might be other options than the ones discussed here, depending on what you mean by "I'm in an interactive session". I.e. some IDEs would allow to define a startup command that could look like `import matplotlib; matplotlib.style.use("ggplot")`.

Comment: That's an interesting idea @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify your required style in a [matplotlibrc format file](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files) in the installation directory.

Edit: on github we find

```
# from http://www.huyng.com/posts/sane-color-scheme-for-matplotlib/

patch.linewidth: 0.5
patch.facecolor: 348ABD  # blue
patch.edgecolor: EEEEEE
patch.antialiased: True

font.size: 10.0

axes.facecolor: E5E5E5
axes.edgecolor: white
axes.linewidth: 1
axes.grid: True
axes.titlesize: x-large
axes.labelsize: large
axes.labelcolor: 555555
axes.axisbelow: True       # grid/ticks are below elements (e.g., lines, text)

axes.prop_cycle: cycler('color', ['E24A33', '348ABD', '988ED5', '777777',     'FBC15E', '8EBA42', 'FFB5B8'])
               # E24A33 : red
               # 348ABD : blue
               # 988ED5 : purple
               # 777777 : gray
               # FBC15E : yellow
               # 8EBA42 : green
               # FFB5B8 : pink

xtick.color: 555555
xtick.direction: out

ytick.color: 555555
ytick.direction: out

grid.color: white
grid.linestyle: -    # solid line

figure.facecolor: white
figure.edgecolor: 0.50
```

Comment: I can't see a setting for 'style' there. If you do this I think you need to specify all the individual settings manually.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/ggplot.mplstyle

Answer (score 1):

You can append

```
use('ggplot')
```

to `.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-2.0.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/style/__init__.py`

Your specific path might look slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, @Roelants answer is correct. Just to go a bit more in detail here:

1. Locate your `matplotlibrc` file as discussed [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files) and make a backup of it.
2. Locate the `ggplot.mplstyle` (might be in a subfolder compared to the `matplotlibrc` file).
3. Replace the content of `matplotlibrc` file by the content of `ggplot.mplstyle`.

From that moment on, the default style will be identical to the one defined by the ggplot style.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to expand upon the answer of @ImportanceOfBeingErnest in a bit more detail.

### How to Permanently Change Default `Matplotlib` Style

This is a three step process where we 1. find out where the `matplotlibrc` file is located 2. copy that file to another location and 3. add the `matplotlibrc` parameters of a specific style. Let's go over each in a bit more detail.

1. Find where the default `matplotlibrc` file is in your computer with the command

```
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.matplotlib_fname())
```

2. Copy the default `matplotlibrc` file into the directory  `$HOME/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc` with the command

```
cp path_matplotlibrc $HOME/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`
```

where path_matplotlibrc is the path where `matplotlibrc` is located, ie path_matplotlibrc is the result of step one.

3. Copy the code from one of the styles files and paste it in the '$HOME/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc` file.

Go to the directory `matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib` (or just go to the same spot in `matplotlib`'s github [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/main/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib)). Copy the code from one of the `.mplstyle` files in that directory. This code will be a list of `matplotlibrc` parameters that correspond to a specific style indicated by the file name. For example, going to github, you can just copy the code for the `fivethirtyeight` style which looks like this.

[image]

Paste the code with that style's `matplotlibrc` parameters at the bottom of the '$HOME/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`file. So in this example we would paste the the`fivethirtyeight`style`matplotlibrc` parameter code depicted above at the end of the new file.

And that's it you are done. Just find out where the `matplotlibrc` file is originally located, copy that file to another location, and add the `matplotlibrc` parameters of a specific style. Pretty simple.

##### Why does this work?

The `matplotlib` documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) explains:

> Matplotlib uses matplotlibrc configuration files to customize all kinds of properties, which we call 'rc settings' or 'rc parameters'. You can control the defaults of almost every property in Matplotlib: figure size and DPI, line width, color and style, axes, axis and grid properties, text and font properties and so on. The matplotlibrc is read at startup to configure Matplotlib... When a style sheet is given with style.use('/.mplstyle'), settings specified in the style sheet take precedence over settings in the matplotlibrc file.

Each style is really a collection of parameters and properties that override the default `matplotlibrc` file found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-default-matplotlibrc-file). We can see this explicitly by looking at the directory `matplotlib/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib` (found on github [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/main/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib)) which contains a file for each built-in style. Click on a file in the directory and we can clearly see that the style is merely a list of `matplotlibrc` parameters. (This is what we showed above, the `fivethirtyeight` `matplotlibrc` parameters.)

So `Matplotlib` uses the `matplotlibrc` file to determine the style of the graphs. Now how does pasting the `matplotlibrc` settings of a certain style in a new file location override the default `matplotlibrc` settings?

`Matplotlib` looks for the `matplotlibrc` file in four locations in the following order:

1. `matplotlibrc` in the current working directory. It is just seeing if a file exists in the current working directory called `matplotlibrc`.
2. `$MATPLOTLIBRC` if it is a file, else `$MATPLOTLIBRC/matplotlibrc`.
3. On Linux and FreeBSD, it looks in `.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc` (or `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/matplotlib/matplotlibrc`) if you've customized your environment. On other platforms, it looks in `.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`.
4. `INSTALL/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`, where `INSTALL` is where you installed the `matplotlib` package. It may be something like `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages` on Linux, and maybe `C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages` on Windows.

Once a `matplotlibrc` file has been found, it will not search any of the other paths.

So by default `matplotlibrc`is only found in location four. This effectively means we can override the default settings found in location 4 by creating a new `matplotlibrc` in locations one, two, or three. By convention you should create a new `matplotlibrc` file in the highest numbered location possible so you can have more room to override that file if need be. In the instructions I just gave, we create a new `matplotlibrc` file in location 3. This is why and how we overrode the default `matplotlibrc` settings, thus creating new `matplotlibrc` settings that correspond to a specific style that is now used by default.

---

A bit more about `Matplotlib` Styles can be found here.

### About `Matplotlib` Styles

`matplotlib` has several built-in styles to choose from. You can see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html) how each built-in style will change how your plots looks. To call a specific style use the command `plt.style.use('stylename')` where `stylename` is any arbitrary style name and to list all available styles, use `print(plt.style.available)`.