# Jupyter notebook: How to set matplotlib figure default size persistently, even after `from matplotlib import pyplot`?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking for a way to configure my default notebook set up and set the size of plots and figures, so that I do not have to set it manually for each notebook individually.

I'm aware of questions like [How to set the matplotlib figure default size in ipython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230797/how-to-set-the-matplotlib-figure-default-size-in-ipython-notebook) which detail how to use `jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

However this isnt working, presumably because I reimport pyplot in the notebook. Is there a better way to set default settings, behaviors, options etc?

Comment: What about using `plt.rc('figure', figsize=(20.0, 10.0))` (as suggested there) after importing pyplot?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander adding `plt.rc('figure', figsize=(20.0, 10.0))` to `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup/startup.ipy` has no effect.

Comment: I think this might be hard if you use matplotlib somewhere else and you want to have other settings there. How should it know if you use it out of IPython or in some other environment? However, if you only use it for IPython, are you aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567808/how-to-permanently-set-matplotlib-pyplot-style), which refers to [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files)?

Comment: I'm looking to set some parameters when I start the notebook server. It _seems_ to be what `jupyter_notebook_config.py` is designed for, but adding commands there has not been successful.

Answer (score 2):

In python 3.x

```
ipython profile create
ipython profile locate
```

go to the locate and edit ipython_kernel_config.py
manually add the line:

```
c.InlineBackend.rc = {'figure.dpi':160}
```

rcParams references

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

Answer (score 1):

One away to set default plot size in matplotlib is:

```
from pylab import rcParams
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 8, 6
```

where 8, 6 is the figure size you want to set.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to set it once as a default for all notebooks, so that I don't have to manually add it to each notebook.